# Boot from an image in PC using Android device

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

I've a Redmi 1S (Hongmi 1S) running MIUI v5 (Jellybean v4.3). I have a Bitdefender [rescue disk](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/) ISO file. I want to boot this rescue disk using my Android phone, just like a bootable USB drive.

- How can I boot from this file in PC using my Android device. What are the necessary requirements?
- Will Android handle this as an ISO file, or will it simply store it as an unknown file type?

I had earlier asked this question on the [MIUI forums](http://en.miui.com/forum.php), but by the next day itself it was stamped irrelevant and was closed/deleted.

As there is no specific date for an upgrade, my device may or may not update to Android 4.4 Kitkat or MIUI v6. So still, will it change with the update?

Comment: [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en) seems interesting.

Comment: does your phone support *usb mass storage*

Comment: @totti ya it supports it Whenever I connect the device it is default in USB mass storage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Why the compulsion to Root , every other unique application in the play store has (Root required). Isn't there any other possible way which doesn't require much messing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image to the hard-disk of an android phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170176/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-hard-disk-of-an-android-phone)

Answer (score 0):

As USB mass storage is available you can use your external memory card as a pen drive. Use any Windows/Linux/Mac  app like  *sardu*, *YUMI* to create bootable USB. Some app may not detect your MMC on phone, then try another boot dirive creater.