# smartphone as a USB ramdisk

Tags: ram, usb-mass-storage, temp-files

Is it possible to use an Android device (like a smartphone) as an USB ramdisk?

Basically i'd like to have the PC accessing a `tmpfs` on the smartphone as a (virtual) USB mass storage device, so data gets written on the smartphone RAM instead of the flash memory.

This could have many use cases:

- emergency swap space for PCs with low RAM
- temporary storage for privacy sensitive-data
- fast storage for temporary files (alternative to a native ramdisk wasting PC RAM)
- PC USB interface benchmarking

Comment: if you think you can do it, just embed your android storage onto the pc: but note: if you use usb (currently usb 3.1 supports **only** 10gibs minus bad transfer,....), I don't expect you have an USB 3.1 android phone and a corresponding pc, so your theoretical maximal data rate would be 60mbps, which is slower than most **hard drives**.

Comment: It still looks interesting to me despite the USB 2.0 bottleneck. Side note: i've found [this commercial app that could do the trick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.devwom.usbsharer) by mounting `/tmp`. I'm going to try it asap.

Comment: by the way there is also a free version.... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.devwom.usbsharereval

Comment: [How to boot an .iso file in PC using Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110312)

Comment: I wouldn't do it as the data rate is far more slower then RAM speed.

Answer (score 1):

[USB Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.devwom.usbsharereval) does the trick by creating a virtual usb image in `/mnt/secure` (which is mounted as `tmpfs` on my Android 4.2 OS). Then, mount and share the image with RW permissions.

Side note:
i've found my OS also mounts a `tmpfs` on `/sdcard/.android_secure` but when connected as USB mass storage the files get written on the flash memory instead of the `tmpfs`.

If you know a better solution not requiring any commercial app please let me know!